# Android SQLite Database holds a single table for a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my project 3 registration forms are there. I provided 3 separate database files and call them in respective registration files accordingly. I gave same database name in all database files and table name varied respective to the forms.

The problem which am facing is database allows me to store a single form registration details only (i.e: if there is User and Doctor registration and I have same database name but table name different). Application allows to store either User or doctor registration.

User registration:

```
            if (username.trim().equals("")&& userage.trim().equals("") && usergender.trim().equals("") && userdob.trim().equals("") && useraddress.trim().equals("") && userpincode.trim().equals("") && userid.trim().equals("") && userpass.trim().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Fields should not empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       /*         UserName.setText("");
                UserAge.setText("");
                UserGender.setText("");
                Userdob.setText("");
                Useraddress.setText("");
                Userpincode.setText("");
                Userid.setText("");
                UserPass.setText("");  */
            }
            else
            {

                try {
                   DatabaseHandler3 db=new DatabaseHandler3(userregistration.this);
                    db.addContact(new Contact(username,userage,usergender,userdob,useraddress,userpincode,userid,userpass));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Registration Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    List<Contact> contacts=db.getAllContacts();
                    for(Contact cn:contacts){
                        String log=cn.getNAME()+"\n"+cn.getAGE()+"\n"+cn.getGENDER()+"\n"+cn.getDOB()+"\n"+cn.getADDRESS()+"\n"+cn.getPINCODE();
                        Toast.makeText(userregistration.this,log,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            //    msq.putinformation(msq,username,userage,usergender,userdob,useraddress,userpincode,userid,userpass);


                finish();
            }
        }
    })   ;


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_userregistration, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Database Handler3 - Userdb:

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DOCROID";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "UserRegistration";




// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_PINCODE = "pincode";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";



private static final String LOGCAT = null;

private static Context context;

 public DatabaseHandler3(Context context) {
     super(context,"/sdcard/DOCROID/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT," + KEY_DOB + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_PINCODE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addContact(Contact contact) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getNAME()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_AGE, contact.getAGE());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, contact.getGENDER()); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(KEY_DOB, contact.getDOB()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getADDRESS());
        values.put(KEY_PINCODE, contact.getPINCODE());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPHONE()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, contact.getPASSWORD());


        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close();

}
 public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setNAME(cursor.getString(0));
                contact.setAGE(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setGENDER(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setDOB(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setADDRESS(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setPINCODE(cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setPHONE(cursor.getString(6));
                contact.setPASSWORD(cursor.getString(7));

                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contactList;


           String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
            db.execSQL(selectQuery);

    }
```

Doctor Registration:

```
            if (docname.trim().equals("") && docage.trim().equals("") && docgender.trim().equals("") && docdob.trim().equals("") && docarea.trim().equals("") && docaddress.trim().equals("") && docpincode.trim().equals("") && docid.trim().equals("") && docpass.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fields should not empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             /*   Doc_name.setText("");
                Doc_age.setText("");
                Doc_gender.setText("");
                Doc_dob.setText("");
                Doc_area.setText("");
                Doc_address.setText("");
                Doc_pincode.setText("");
                Doc_id.setText("");
                Doc_pass.setText(""); */
            } else {

                try {
                    DatabaseHandler4 db1 = new DatabaseHandler4(docregistration.this);
                    db1.addContact(new Contact1(docname, docage, docgender, docdob, docarea, docaddress, docpincode, docid, docpass));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    List<Contact1> contacts = db1.getAllContacts();
                    for (Contact1 cn : contacts) {
                        String log = cn.getDNAME() + "\n" + cn.getDAGE() + "\n" + cn.getDGENDER() + "\n" + cn.getDDOB() + "\n" + cn.getDAREA() + "\n" + cn.getDADDRESS() + "\n" + cn.getDPINCODE();
                        Toast.makeText(docregistration.this, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finish();

            }
```

DatabaseHandler4 - doctor db:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DOCROID";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS1 = "docregistration";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_DNAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_DAGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_DGENDER = "gender";
private static final String KEY_DDOB = "dob";
private static final String KEY_DAREA = "area";
private static final String KEY_DADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_DPINCODE = "pincode";
private static final String KEY_DPH_NO = "phone";
private static final String KEY_DPASSWORD = "password";


private static final String LOGCAT = null;

private static Context context;

public DatabaseHandler4(Context context) {
    super(context,"/sdcard/DOCROID/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS1 + "("
            + KEY_DNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_DAGE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DGENDER + " TEXT," + KEY_DDOB + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DAREA + " TEXT," + KEY_DADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DPINCODE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DPH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_DPASSWORD + " TEXT" + ");";
    db1.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE1);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db1, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addContact(Contact1 contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DNAME, contact.getDNAME());
    values.put(KEY_DAGE, contact.getDAGE());
    values.put(KEY_DGENDER, contact.getDGENDER());
    values.put(KEY_DDOB, contact.getDDOB());
    values.put(KEY_DAREA, contact.getDAREA());
    values.put(KEY_DADDRESS, contact.getDADDRESS());
    values.put(KEY_DPINCODE, contact.getDPINCODE());
    values.put(KEY_DPH_NO, contact.getDPHONE());
    values.put(KEY_DPASSWORD, contact.getDPASSWORD());


    // Inserting Row
    db1.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS1, null, values);
    db1.close();

}
public List<Contact1> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact1> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact1>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS1;

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact1 contact = new Contact1();
            contact.setDNAME(cursor.getString(0));
            contact.setDAGE(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setDGENDER(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setDDOB(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setDAREA(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setDADDRESS(cursor.getString(5));
            contact.setDPINCODE(cursor.getString(6));
            contact.setDPHONE(cursor.getString(7));
            contact.setDPASSWORD(cursor.getString(8));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using 3 databases with one table each rather than one database with 3 tables? When using multiple database files, you have to manually close the entire database and open the other one. You are much better off using 1 database.

Comment: You can create all tables in the same database handler class. There is no need to make different handler classes. First uninstall your app and reinstall from device then run your app after doing the things I mentioned. That will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using 1 database with multiple tables. It's not that hard to accomplish either and much easier to handle.

If you need a sample code there are a lot floating around on the internet but here's one of mine if you need it ( it has 5 tables ).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TERMS + " (" + colTermsID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colTermsClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PERIODS + " (" + colPeriodID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colPeriodClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + STATUS + " (" + colStatusID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colStatClass + " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ACCOUNTS + " (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colName + " TEXT, " +
            colAmount + " Integer, " +
            colPurpose + " TEXT, " +
            colTerms + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPeriod +" INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colBalance +" INTEGER, "+
            colStatus + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            colDate + " TEXT, " +
            colEditDate + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colTerms + ") REFERENCES " + TERMS + " (" + colTermsID + " )" + "," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colPeriod + ") REFERENCES " + PERIODS + " (" + colPeriodID + ") " + ","+
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colStatus + ") REFERENCES " + STATUS + " (" + colStatusID + "));");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PAYMENTS + " (" + colPayID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
            colGroupID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colPayBal + " TEXT, " +
            colInterest + " TEXT, " +
            colPayDue + " TEXT, " +
            colDateDue + " TEXT, " +
            colPaid + " Integer, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colGroupID + ") REFERENCES " + ACCOUNTS + " (" + colID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);");
```